# Azure ADAL authentication using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to authenticate azure using ADAL, I am following azure docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python

I am getting error

`msrest.exceptions.AuthenticationError: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: be8e6b37-71dc-4a03-a6d5-8c1ea0c91900\r\nCorrelation ID: 0c1cb916-3250-4176-be9e-d951b8ec7203\r\nTimestamp: 2018-12-21 11:03:22Z","error_codes":[70002,50012],"timestamp":"2018-12-21 11:03:22Z","trace_id":"be8e6b37-71dc-4a03-a6d5-8c1ea0c91900","correlation_id":"0c1cb916-3250-4176-be9e-d951b8ec7203"}`

I am sure that i am using correct `TENANT_ID` `CLIENT` and `KEY`.

Here is my code from docs

```
import adal
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AdalAuthentication
from msrestazure.azure_cloud import AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

# Tenant ID for your Azure Subscription
TENANT_ID = 'bef06fb1-f1d7-4b31-9a96-xxfx5xx5xbx2x7'

# Your Service Principal App ID
CLIENT = '8ce61571-35c4-43ce-94ae-7xx1xex2x5x9'

# Your Service Principal Password
KEY = 'SoafGHAvu2EyTdSvxWQo/1XnlKRoaf89eDuuQiCnptc='

subscription_id = '020dd0e6-f63c-4e76-825c-02faad1d8d18'

LOGIN_ENDPOINT = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory
RESOURCE = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory_resource_id

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(LOGIN_ENDPOINT + '/' + TENANT_ID)
credentials = AdalAuthentication(
    context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials,
    RESOURCE,
    CLIENT,
    KEY
)

client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
vmlist = client.virtual_machines.list_all()

for vm in vmlist:
    print(vm.name)
```

`

Comment: Could you try the pure ADAL sample: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/18a985c7f3f8eb6b5e35bd9df90a08ad8bccb42e/sample/client_credentials_sample.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, I think you did not give the role to your service principal at the `subscription` scope.

[image]

To fix the issue, you could try to navigate to your `subscription` -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add role assignment` -> Add a `Owner` role(for example) to your service principal.

Then it will work fine.

[image]

For more details about Azure RBAC, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).